# NHibernate LINQ Timeout

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I need to set the timeout for a NHibernate LINQ Query. Event though I have written the code and the code compiles at runtime I get error

```
"Method not found: 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1<!!0> NHibernate.Linq.LinqExtensionMethods.Timeout(System.Linq.IQueryable`1<!!0>, Int32)
```

The version being used in is

```
   `<package id="NHibernate" version="3.3.3.4001" targetFramework="net452" />`
```

The code looks something like this

```
    var gpq = (from spg in session.Query<Table1>()
              join spgm in session.Query<Table2>() 
on spg.Table1Key equals spgm.Table2Key join sp in session.Query<Table3>() on spgm.Table2ID equals sp.Table3ID orderby spg.Table1ID
                                select spg).Timeout(120).Distinct();
                            var groups = gpq.ToList();
```

Can someone please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: sounds like Linq 2 Sql is trying to translate Timeout to a sql query. What happens if you try,  var gqp = ....Distinct(); gpq.Timeout(120); var groups = gpq.ToList();?

Comment: @LowFlyingPelican: Getting same error with that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Timeout()` returns a new `IQueryable`, you'll need to assign it or chain it:

```
var gpq = (
   from spg in session.Query<Table1>()
   join spgm in session.Query<Table2>() on spg.Table1Key equals spgm.Table2Key 
   join sp in session.Query<Table3>() on spgm.Table2ID equals sp.Table3ID 
   orderby spg.Table1ID
   select spg
).Distinct();

var groups = gpq.Timeout(120).ToList();
```

However, looking at the source, there's an `Obsolete` attribute on the `Timeout()` method. It says use the `WithOptions()` method instead:

```
var groups = qpq.WithOptions(options => options.SetTimeout(120)).ToList();
```